# How to generate variables with common latent factor?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, simulation, multicollinearity, latent-variable

I'm dealing with Kalnins (2018) [work](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/smj.2783) about multicollinearity. I can't comprehend one thing - how can I get variables that share a common latent factor? (not only correlate with each other).

I can generate any set of data with fixed correlation values between random variables, but despite the high correlation I do not get (multi)collinearity breaking regression asumptions. I understand that this Kalnins' collinearity (when regression model turns bad) occurs when the variables are not only correlated but also have a common latent factor. In fact, I am a bit helpless, because I do not understand in what mathematical relations the variables should remain with each other in order to obtain such a common latent factor.

Since I work in the social sciences, I would like to understand this concept with some example in social sciences (if possible). I know that I can generate a set of data with simulated questionnaire results (four variables, integer values in the range 1-20), like this:

```
28,28,26,26
22,16,26,8
29,17,27,29
24,12,14,24
22,6,4,8
20,28,28,28
27,17,29,27
16,30,30,4
14,14,8,2
2,8,6,6
2,2,18,14
7,11,7,7
10,10,2,12
3,1,1,5
23,27,25,29
23,7,11,13
15,25,13,27
14,18,18,16
27,21,25,29
```

and then how to get common latent factor? Should some individual cases have identical results for all variables? Maybe the point is that the variables should be in some linear relation to each other? But they are, they are correlated and quite strongly! Maybe all these variables should be a function of some other variable? How to understand it, how to get it?

Thank you very much in advance for any tips

Answer (score 4):

The diagram below (from [here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/what-is-a-latent-variable/)) sketches out the most commonly-used kind of latent factor model.

[image]

Scores on the $x$ variables are modelled as the score on the latent factor $z$, weighted by the factor weights $\lambda$, plus the noise terms $\delta$ (each of which has a mean of zero and a specific standard deviation).

This is pretty simple to simulate (using R, and keeping the code simple):

```r
N = 1000
n_variables = 3
z = rnorm(N, 0, 1)
weights = runif(n_variables, .5, 1) # Random weights

noise1 = rnorm(N, 0, .5)
noise2 = rnorm(N, 0, .2)
noise3 = rnorm(N, 0, .7)
noise_y = rnorm(N, 0, .1)

# Observed variables reflect latent factor plus noise
x1 = z * weights[1] + noise1
x2 = z * weights[2] + noise2
x3 = z * weights[3] + noise3

# y is predicted by x1 and x2
y = .1 * x1 + .1 * x2 + noise_y

X = data.frame(x1, x2, x3, y)
```

[image]

```r
m = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = X)
m_coefs = coef(summary(m))
round(m_coefs, 3)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)    0.004      0.003   1.380    0.168
# x1             0.108      0.006  17.550    0.000
# x2             0.095      0.007  13.404    0.000
# x3             0.000      0.004   0.083    0.934
```

Comment: From my simple point of view common latent variable here means, that variables x1-x2 are just a transformation of z + noise, right? The code you provide does indeed lead to collinearity, but "weak" (only gives false negative errors, but no false positive errors). I tried to modify your code by changing f.e. N, type of distribution, number of variables, but I cannot get what is shown in the Kalnins article. Maybe I should generate the dependent variable in a completely different way to reproduce the sign change of the predictor mentioned in the article?

Comment: You have two questions here, "How to generate variables with common latent factor?", and "How to generate data that recapitulates the problems discussed in the Kalnins paper?". I can only see the abstract for that paper, but AFAIK the claim **If regressors are correlated via an unobservable common factor, estimated beta coefficients will misleadingly tend toward infinite magnitudes in opposite directions, even if the variables’ real effects are small and of the same sign.** is just plain wrong without some additional constraints.

Comment: I've updated my code to show this, but it seems like you've reached the same conclusion anyway.

Comment: OK, i need to read some more. I'll be back to this topic. Meanwhile - can You tell me what "some additional constraints" are needed here, and what works You recommend to read about this claim?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, sorry. It's pretty clear that just correlation via an unobservable common factor isn't enough though.